# XNA can't find File

Tags: c#, xna

I already tried alot and it doesnt work. I'm trying to start programing a game with XNA. So, I tried to load an Image. But it can't find it. This is my code

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture character;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        character = Content.Load<Texture2D>("pic");
    }
```

So, for me there isnt a mistake. I added the picture by clickend with right click on **Game_Test** and then **add existing item**. Game_Test is the name of the project
Does anyone know where the mistake could be?

Comment: Is the picture in the Content directory, is it copied during build as a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it not to "Game_Test" but to "Game_TestContent".

This is the place where XNA searching for Content.

for example my project called XNA_Tutorial, so i added to the yellow marked project : 
[image]